# mplfinance plot tight_layout cuts information off

Tags: python, mplfinance

first must say, I love the mplfinance, it is a very nice way to display data on the chart.

my problem now is, I cant reduce the space to the borders. There is a parameter calle "tight_layout" but it cuts information off. Probably I do something wrong.

```
mpf.plot(df_history, show_nontrading=True, figratio=(10,7), figscale=1.5, datetime_format='%d.%m.%y', 
         xrotation=90, tight_layout=True,  
         alines=dict(alines=seq_of_points, colors=seq_of_colors, linestyle='-', linewidths=0.5),
         type='candle', savefig=bildpfad, addplot=apdict, 
         update_width_config=dict(candle_linewidth=0.4))
```

When I use `tight_layout=True`, it lookes like this:
[image]
The space around the chart is perfekt, but the data in the chart is cut off.

and if I use `tight_layout=False` it uses too much space and the html file created looks crooked.
[image]

Does anybody know the right way?

Comment: Is the time series of the additional graph the same as the candlestick graph? Also, what if the additional graph is not drawn?

Comment: the green additional line is just another column in the dataframe of the candlestick graph. At the end of the date the green extension is just a line defined by 2 points, drawn from the end of the data to a cetain date, like the red or the blue line on the top

Comment: Do you have the same symptoms without the additional graph?

Comment: Well, I think there is no mistake. The tight layout just displays the whole data in the dataframe and reduces the picture according to this. It looks like there is nothing missed. But the additional 'alines' keyword is getting ignored when using tight_layout=True. The thing is, I miss is the additional lines which I drew.

Comment: maybe it is also the keyword show_nontrading=True which is ignored

Comment: I don't know the name of the stock, and I don't have any information about the additional graphs, so I can't reproduce it in my environment. The graphs without the additional graphs are identical regardless of whether there is a tight layout or not.

Comment: the name of the stock is CSCO, from 08.09.20 d/m/y till 21.05.21. If you want to add two points into seq_of_points you can add 12.03.2021 with 34.81 and 21.05.21 with 
34.81. 
thx a lot for trying to help.

Comment: I understand your issue. `tight_layout=True` does not show the full range of the y-axis. The margins may also be an issue, but you're forcing the drawing range to be extended and truncated.

Comment: Why don't you post your current issue [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different things you can do to fix this.  First, understand the reason why this is happening.  The `tight_layout` algorithm sets the x-axis limits to just outside the limits of your dataframe datetime index, whereas some of your `alines` points are obviously outside of this range.  Given that, there are a few things you can do:

- use kwarg `xlim=(xmin,xmax)` to manually set the x-axis limits that you want.
- pad the end of you ohlc dataframe with `nan` values out to the latest date that you need on your plot.
- request a bug fix or enhancement that `tight_layout` should take `alines` into account.

HTH.

---

**P.S.**  Presently `xlim` only accepts numbers (int or float) that correspond to row numbers in your dataframe (or that correspond to matplotlib dates, see P.P.S. below).  I hope to enhance `xlim` to accept dates sometime soon.  In the meantime, try somthing like this:

```py
xmin = 0
xmax = len(df_history)*1.4
mpf.plot(df_history,...,xlim=(xmin,xmax))
```

---

**P.P.S.**  I just realized that the above (`xmax = len(df_history)*1.4`) will work only for `show_nontrading=False`.  However with `show_nontrading=True` as you have it, you will need to set xmax and xmin differently, as:

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
...

# decide how many days past the end of the data 
# that you want the maximum x-axis limit to be:
numdays = 10
# then:
xmin = mdates.date2num(df_history.index[0].to_py_datetime())
xmax = mdates.date2num(df_history.index[-1].to_py_datetime()) + numdays
mpf.plot(df_history,...,xlim=(xmin,xmax))
```

(notice above they are not both `.index[0]` but xmax derives from `.index[-1]`)

---

My apologies that the above work-arounds for `xlim` are elaborate.  This is motivating me even more to finish the `xlim` enhancement so that users can just pass in a date as a string or datetime.  Users of mplfinance should not have to worry about these date conversion details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. Godlfarb, 
as I am very new to python I cant get it done:
a test with xlim_koord = (datetime(2000, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 12, 31)) trhrows the error:
TypeError: kwarg "xlim" validator returned False for value: "(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0))"
    'Validator'    : lambda value: isinstance(value, (list,tuple)) and len(value) == 2

Comment: My bad.  I forgot that `xlim` needs to be enhanced to accept dates.  Currently it accepts numbers that correspond to the row number in your dataframe.  I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: thank you again very much for you good advices.
Had a Problem with 
`xmin = mdates.date2num(df_history.index[0].to_py_datetime())`, had to reduce it to `mdates.date2num(df_history.index[0])` because of the AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'to_py_datetime'.

It worsk now, with the x-axis, but there is the problem, that die lines beneeth the chart  are not shown because they visibility is reduced to the lowest price in the chart. I think, probably your advice #2 is the next best one, to pad the dataframe with nan-values. I will try it. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The advice #2 (padding with nan's) probably won't work too, because the tight_layout=True cuts the picture according to the lowest or highest price in the chart.

Comment: If necessary you can adjust the price limits with kwarg `ylim=(ymin,ymax)`.  Then perhaps you can do the `nan` padding with `tight_layout`.